# Want to make it so when button is press the chat gui and the server starts but just getting connection refused?

Tags: sockets, user-interface, tkinter, connection

I'm trying to make it so when I press the sign on the button, it should get the IP and PORT from the entry boxes like it does for the client, however, the client seems to not want to connect, which doesn't make sense, as when I ran the server on it's own, the GUI would work and the client connected. I think it may be the "IF name == main" function but I need assistance of thats the case .

Here is the server code:

```
# imports
import socket
import threading
from threading import Lock
import select




# Servers address and port (inputted)

def set_address_and_port(ip, port):
    global SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT
    SERVER_ADDRESS = ip
    SERVER_PORT = port
    return SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT


# client handler that should echo the clients message back
data_lock = Lock()
connected_clients: list[(str, socket.socket, threading.Thread)] = []


# connected_clients: dict(str, (socket, threading)) = {}

def start_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Server is listening on {SERVER_ADDRESS}:{SERVER_PORT}")

    while True:
        server_socket.settimeout(5.0)
        try:
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()  # Give this a time out so it doesn't block forever
        except TimeoutError:
            pass
        else:
            # If a client connected, do the stuff below
            print(f"Client connected: {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

            list_of_addresses = [addy for (addy, _, _) in connected_clients]

            if client_address[0] not in list_of_addresses:
                client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
                connected_clients.append((client_address[0], client_socket, client_thread))
                client_thread.start()
                # Save the client thread in connected_clients so we can check if its alive

            else:
                for (addy, sock, thread) in connected_clients:
                    if addy == client_address[0]:
                        sock.close()
                        # Kill the thread...

        # Once you've dealt with any connections, check for any disconnections:
        for (address, client_socket, thread) in connected_clients:
            # If the thread for this client is not alive, remove it from connected_clients
            if not thread.is_alive():
                # Remove this client from connected_clients
                if client_socket in connected_clients:
                    connected_clients.remove((address, client_socket, thread))
                    break


def disconnect(client_socket):
    client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)


def relay_message(client_address, message):
    print(f"Received from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}: {message}")

    def send_to_one_client(user_sock):
        _, ready_write, in_error = select.select([], [user_sock], [user_sock])
        if user_sock in ready_write and not (user_sock in in_error):
            user_sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            print("Could not send to client...")

    # map iterates over 'shared memory' so
    with data_lock:
        for (_, user_socket, _) in connected_clients:
            send_to_one_client(user_socket)


# client handler that should echo the clients message back
def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    while True:
        try:
            ready_read, _, in_error = select.select([client_socket], [], [client_socket])
            if client_socket in in_error:
                print("Error reading from socket...")
                break
            elif client_socket in ready_read:
                message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

                if message:
                    relay_message(client_address, message)
                else:
                    print('No data received on read. Closing client connection')
                    client_socket.close()
                    return

        except select.error as e:  # No data to receive
            print('Socket error. Closing socket')
            print(e)
            client_socket.close()
            return

    # client_socket.close()
    # with data_lock:
    #     for item in connected_clients:
    #         (addy, socket) = item
    #         if socket == client_socket:
    #             connected_clients.remove(item)
    #             break


# starts the server again


if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_address_and_port()
    start_server()
```

And heres the Code for the startup GUI. When the sign on button is press I want the server and the GUI/client to start if there isn't already a server on that address.

```
from pathlib import Path
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from CHAT_GUI_FUNCTIONS import chat_gui
from server import start_server, set_address_and_port


def server_boot():
    set_address_and_port(ip, port)

    if set_address_and_port(ip, port) == (ip, port):
        print('nope')

    else:
        start_server()


def ip():
    ip = entry_ip.get()
    SERVER_ADDRESS = ip
    return SERVER_ADDRESS


# Get the port from the enter port
def port():
    ep = entry_port.get()
    print(ep)
    try:
        port = int(ep)
    except ValueError as e:
        port = 1234

    SERVER_PORT = port
    return SERVER_PORT


def usernames():
    usernames = entry_name.get()
    username = usernames
    return username


def chat_gui_button_wrapper():
    server_boot()

    chat_gui(ip(), port(), usernames())


# playsound.playsound('welcomecopy.mp3')

# Sets the theme to light
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('light')

# set up the main window
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry('300x500')
root.title('Sign On')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(5, weight=2)
root.rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)

# add a label to the window
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="COL Instant Messenger", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 25))

# load images.
canvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(root)
directory = Path.home()
im = Image.open(f"{directory}/PycharmProjects/Messaging-APP/image/colloginscreen.png").resize((300, 250))
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
canvas.create_image(150, 100, image=logo)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3)
# 506x462

# sets up the entry box for username input

entry_name = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root, placeholder_text="ScreenName...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                    width=150)
entry_name.grid(column=1, row=4)

entry_ip = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root, placeholder_text="Enter IP...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                  width=150)
entry_ip.grid(column=1, row=5)

entry_port = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root, placeholder_text="Enter Port...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                    width=150)
entry_port.grid(column=1, row=6)

# Add a button to the window
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text='Sign On', fg_color="#d3d333", border_color="black", text_color="black",
                                 font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15), command=chat_gui_button_wrapper)
button.grid(column=1, row=7)

# start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

heres the function for the actual chat GUI:

```
# function version of gui to go into updated sign in page
def chat_gui(ip, port, usernames):
    # imports
    import customtkinter as ctk
    import socket
    import threading

    # server  address and port
    SERVER_ADDRESS = ip
    SERVER_PORT = port
    username = usernames

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
    client_socket.setblocking(False)

    # GUI WINDOW size and appearance
    chat = ctk.CTk()
    chat.geometry('900x600')
    chat.title('COL Instant Messenger')
    ctk.set_appearance_mode('light')

    # Press enter to send message
    def handle_return_key(event):
        send_message()

    # send message function used in the button
    def send_message():

        message = f'{username}: {message_entry.get()}'
        message_entry.delete(0, len(message))

        client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

    # columns and row configuration
    chat.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    chat.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    chat.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    chat.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    chat.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    chat.rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
    chat.rowconfigure(3, weight=3)
    chat.rowconfigure(4, weight=0)

    # message entry box
    message_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=chat, placeholder_text="Message Here...", font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15),
                                 width=300)
    message_entry.bind(sequence='<Return>', command=handle_return_key)

    message_entry.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky="ew", pady=20)

    # send message button
    send_button = ctk.CTkButton(chat, text="send", command=send_message, hover=True, width=100)
    send_button.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")

    # textbox, currently not working for some reason, won't print message into it,
    textbox = ctk.CTkTextbox(chat)
    textbox.configure(font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15))
    textbox.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')

    textbox_client_list = ctk.CTkTextbox(chat)
    textbox_client_list.configure(font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15))
    textbox_client_list.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')

    # insert code for receiving new network messages
    def received_messages():
        while True:
            try:
                # Receive the echoed message from the server
                received_message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                client_socket.close()

                # Display the received message in the GUIs textbox
                textbox.configure(state='normal', text_color="black")
                textbox.insert("end", f"Received: {received_message}\n")
                textbox.configure(state="disabled", text_color="black",
                                  font=("Times New Roman Pixel", 15))  # configure textbox to be read-only
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break

    send_receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=received_messages)
    send_receive_thread.start()

    # updates chat
    while True:
        chat.update_idletasks()
        chat.update()
        try:
            received_message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if received_message:
                textbox.configure(state="normal")
                textbox.insert("end", f"{received_message}\n")
                textbox.configure(state="disabled")

        except Exception as e:
            pass
            # print(e)
            # break
    # chat.mainloop()
```

I tried to implement it in a similar way to the function for the GUI by making the whole server a function but I've just been getting the connection refused error, I've also got my current attempt which is to use the port() and the ip() functions to get the IP and PORT for the server, however this is still getting me a connection refused error (Erno 61) and I'm just completely lost.

Comment: Have you ever tried to print out messages for simple debugging? Inside `server_boot()`, what do you think the returned value of `set_address_and_port(ip, port)`? What do think the values of `ip` and `port`?

Comment: @acw1668 The message inside server boot prints, which I think means that it's saying theres already a device on that address, but there isn't, the IP and PORT functions get the Ip and the port that the user enters inside of the gui, it works for the client so I don't understand why it wouldn't work for the server. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: `ip` and `port` are functions and `set_address_and_port(ip, port)` just returns back `ip, port`.  Therefore `set_address_and_port(ip, port) == (ip, port)` always be `True` and `start_server()` will never be executed.

Comment: @acw1668 So if i did set_address_and_port(ip, port) == 0, would that do the trick, if not how would i detect if an address is already in use?

Comment: Maybe you would want to run this code at the start of your code to create permissions?```import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context```